# How to persist the state of a custom Android View?

Tags: android, android-view, multi-touch

I want to manipulate a library I just discovered to drag/rotate and pinch zoom images. I am using two sources:

-The library itself: MultiTouchController.java https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/MTController/src/org/metalev/multitouch/controller/MultiTouchController.java

-An implementation of this library: `PhotoSortrView` https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/MTPhotoSortr/src/org/metalev/multitouch/photosortr/PhotoSortrView.java

-an example of `Activity` which implements this source:

```
public class PhotoSortrActivity extends Activity {

    PhotoSortrView photoSorter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
            photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
            setContentView(photoSorter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            photoSorter.loadImages(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            photoSorter.unloadImages();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                    photoSorter.trackballClicked();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

}

The problem is the activity doesn't remember the position of the images when it leaves the foreground and I recall it after. Worse, the images are set randomly each time the `Activity` is called.

How can I make the `Activity` remember the state of the images? (the specific issue in my case is that it is a custom view)

Here is an example of what I want the Activity to remember, and then the reset made by the Activity after being called again:
 [image: Here is an example of what I want the Activity to remember:]

[image: Here is the Activity after I recall it:]

Comment: Better post a screenshot, upload image somewhere ad put a link here

Comment: @Apurva I added some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

See the `savedInstanceState` parameter in `onCreate()`?  You override `onSaveInstanceState()` to set up a bundle that remembers your Activity state, and it shows up in the `onCreate()`.

Now, if your question is: How do you save Activity state without changing the `PhotoSortrView` class; well, you can't.  You would have to add some state parameter to `loadImages()` so that it loads the images and sets the current image, and maybe change `unloadImages()` so that it returns some state information that the Activity can save.

Comment: I don't understand, can I do what I want just by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` or do I have to do both the override and some changes in the `PhotoSortrView` class?

Comment: Since the interface to PhotoSortrView doesn't provide any way to set up the images once they're loaded, you'll have to make some changes to PhotoSortrView to pass the state information between the PhotoSortrView and the Activity, as well as override onSaveInstanceState().